# How to change the button text of FileDialog?

Tags: java, awt

How do you change the button text of FileDialog (not JFileChooser)?  The two modes specify the button text:

```
FileDialog.LOAD -> "Open"
FileDialog.SAVE -> "Save"
```

But I want the button to say something else.  Is it possible to change this text?

Comment: Question edited: Swing tag removed and AWT tag added. FileDialog is not a Swing class but rather an AWT class.

Comment: Why use AWT?   See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255106/java-gui-listeners-without-awt/6255978#6255978) for many good reasons to abandon AWT using components in favor of Swing.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I agree about using Swing over AWT.  The only AWT component in the whole app is FileDialog since on OS X, Swing's JFileChooser looks terrible.

Answer (score 1):

You cant change button text only with FileDialog methods, the only text you can edit in it is window's title which opens when you press for example "Open".

```
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(FdExample.this, "select File", FileDialog.LOAD);
fd.setTitle("any new title");
```

If you want custom text in button, you can use JButton and ActionListener to activate FileDialog.
Probably this will be the best way.

Answer (score 0):

```
FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(Display.getDefault().getActiveShell(),SWT.SAVE);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.  In particular, where is the text you're assigning to the button labels?